# How deal with the UndefinedUnitError？

Tags: python, unit-testing, metpy

**I downloaded data from noaa and i wanted to calculate vertical velocity using the function *vertical_velocity=metpy.calcmpcalc.vertical_velocity(omega,pressure,temperature)*. But something wrong when i dealing with the units of varibles.**

```
import xarray as xr
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
omega=xr.open_dataset('D:\\data_english\\jwk\\omega.mon.mean.nc')

temperature=xr.open_dataset('D:\\data_english\\jwk\\air.mon.mean.nc')

height=xr.open_dataset('D:\\data_english\\jwk\\hgt.mon.mean.nc')

pressure=mpcalc.height_to_pressure_std(height['hgt'])

verticalwind=mpcalc.vertical_velocity(omega['omega'], pressure, temperature['air'])


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-194-da22b63a1943>", line 1, in <module>
    verticalwind=mpcalc.vertical_velocity(omega['omega'], pressure, temperature['air'])
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\metpy\xarray.py", line 1199, in wrapper
    _mutate_arguments(bound_args, xr.DataArray, lambda arg, _: arg.metpy.unit_array)
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\metpy\xarray.py", line 1233, in _mutate_arguments
    bound_args.arguments[arg_name] = mutate_arg(arg_val, arg_name)
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\metpy\xarray.py", line 1199, in <lambda>
    _mutate_arguments(bound_args, xr.DataArray, lambda arg, _: arg.metpy.unit_array)
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\metpy\xarray.py", line 157, in unit_array
    return units.Quantity(self._data_array.data, self.units)
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\metpy\xarray.py", line 134, in units
    return units.parse_units(self._data_array.attrs.get('units', 'dimensionless'))
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pint\registry.py", line 1084, in parse_units
    units = self._parse_units(input_string, as_delta)
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pint\registry.py", line 1298, in _parse_units
    return super()._parse_units(input_string, as_delta)
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pint\registry.py", line 1112, in _parse_units
    cname = self.get_name(name)
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pint\registry.py", line 636, in get_name
    raise UndefinedUnitError(name_or_alias)
UndefinedUnitError: 'Pascal' is not defined in the unit registry
```

**The units of omega, height and temperature are 'Pascal/s', 'm' and 'degC', repectively. The varible pressure was calculate through the function *mpcalc.height_to_pressure_std*, and this function didn't give the unit of pressure. But the values of pressure range from 1000 to 0, so i think its unit is 'hpa'.

The error reported that "'Pascal' is not defined in the unit registry". Maybe 'Pascal/s' is not the default unit of omega? But how can i know which units are defined in the unit registry ? Can anyone help me? Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem where the unit library MetPy uses (Pint) does not have the same rules about capitalization/case sensitivity as the UDUnits format used by the netCDF Climate and Forecasting Conventions for metadata. [Fixing this](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/1362) is on MetPy's todo list, but some roadblocks have been encountered.

The work-around right now is to change your units to something that Pint understands, like:

```
omega['omega'].attrs['units'] = 'pascal / s'
```

Comment: Great! Be sure to mark this answer as accepted then.